# IDEA run a sampe code and get the issue: java: illegal character：'#'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IDEA version： 2021.3.2

JAVA version: 1.8.0

The encoding format is UTF-8

I am a beginner in java, I try to install IEDA and run a sample code to output "HelloWorld", then get the error `java: illegal character：'#'` and other errors

[image]

What I tried:

1. Check the env path, right.
2. Create a `txt` file-> enter test code-> change the file type to `.java`, then run the cmd `javac test.java` and `java xxx`, it output `HelloWorld`
3. Change the encoding format to GBK and then back to UTF-8
4. Add `-encoding UTF8` in IDEA settings

[image]

update1

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Just a test");
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be easier if you showed the code you are trying to execute

Comment: post the whole source code in the test file

Comment: Thanks, update the code, just print Helloworld. @Stultuske

Comment: according to your images, you are trying to execute "tests.java"

Comment: Hi @Stultuske, Yes, and then i create a new test file and get the same issue, then I try to create a txt file and copy the code, then change the file type to java, then run the cmd, and it print the output

Comment: What encoding is [set for this file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/encoding.html#single-file)? Make sure to try it with `UTF-8`.

Comment: Hi @Andrey, the encoding is set for UTF-8